# I make a backup of my users in active directory and restore it on another server

Tags: active-directory

need to spend all organization unit folders, containing the names of all my users who log into their corresponding session, and restore it on another server that is also active directory domain server

Comment: I appreciate that English may not be your first language, but I personally am having some trouble understanding your question.  Could you expand a little further?

Comment: sorry ..let you explain.. I have a domain server, where I stored the names of my users and their accounts with which they come to their session on the computer, then I need to spend all these users to a new domain server

Comment: Are you trying to replace a domain controller, add a new one or something else? If trying to add or replace a domain controller, you should read up on the DCPROMO command. If you are trying to do something else, please explain an overview of what you are trying to do, rather than specific steps you think you need to perform, as you might well be asking the wrong question.

Comment: Is the new DC already in the same domain as the old DC?  Is the new DC in a different domain?

Comment: The new DC is the same of the old DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aiming to effectively stage an identical copy of you AD to a separate server (for testing or something) you can use the Group policy management console (GPMC) to export your entire domain to an xml file which you can import into a different AD. This will very effectively create a "copy" of all your OUs, GPOs, and even users/groups. Bear in mind, passwords are not migrated this way.

Language barriers aside, it is VERY important that you do not do this if you're trying to replace an old domain controller with a new one, or add a second domain controller to the same domain.

You'll find some sample scripts for GPMC-based exports here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=38C1A89B-A6D2-4F2A-A944-9236999AEE65&displaylang=en

Comment: Just to clarify: afaik, you cannot do this directly from the gpmc console. you have to do it with wsh from a command line using the scripts provided with the gpmc. for instance, to create an xml from your environment you would run the following from a command line: C:\Program Files\GPMC\Scripts>cscript CreateXMLFromEnvironment.wsf filename.xml /options

Answer (score 1):

If your newDC is in the *same* domain as the oldDC, then all the domain accounts will already be on the newDC.

If the newDC is in a *different* domain to oldDC, then you will need to use the [Active Directory Migration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AE279D01-7DCA-413C-A9D2-B42DFB746059&displaylang=en).

If you need to use the ADMT, let us know as there are some special requirements you need first (domain trusts, an account with Domain Admin privs in both domains etc)